# Animate div on dynamic image click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: on page load get a bunch of images from the DB and attach them to gallery div, when clicking on a gallery image: fade out current big main image -> replace the source of the faded image to the source of the clicked small image -> animate the main image's div container to the new image height -> fade the main image back in.

I have this code:

```
$.getJSON('inc/API.php',
{
    command: "get_ads_to_display"
},
function(result){
    $("#img_main").attr('src', 'images/'+result[0].ad_image_filename);
    for(var i = 0; i<result.length; i++)
    {
        $("<div class='div_item_container'>"+
            "<div class='div_ad_name'>"+result[i].ad_publisher+"</div>"+
            "<div class='div_ad_image'><img src='images/"+result[i].ad_image_filename+"' /></div>"+
        "</div>").appendTo("#gallery");
    }

    // Channge main image src to src of a clicked image
    //animate the main image div's height
    $('.div_item_container').on('click', '.div_ad_image img', function() {
        var src = $(this).attr('src');
        $("#img_main").fadeTo(200,0,function(){
            $("#img_main").attr('src', src);
            var img = document.getElementById('img_main'); 
            var img_height = img.clientHeight;
            //alert(img_height);
            $("#div_main_image_container").animate({height:img_height+10+'px'},250,function(){
                $("#img_main").fadeTo(200,1);
            });

        });
    });
});
```

It works, except for the first click - on the first click on any of the gallery images I don't have the div animation, it just changes the size of the div, replaces the image src and fades back in. After that I have a good animation of the div's height. Why is it happening and is there a way to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem: the gallery div didn't have any initial height property defined. Once I defined it in CSS (even `height:0;` worked) - everything worked great.

Answer (score 0):

You need to delegate your event to some element that is not created dynamically -

`$('#gallery').on('click', '.div_ad_image img', function() {`

`#gallery` instead of `.div_item_container`(*you are appending this in a loop right ?*)

Comment: The gallery div is static, and the `div class='div_item_container` are appended dynamically, yes. I tried to delegate it to `#gallery`, but it still doesn't animate on first click.